# Could not open input file: artisan error in react laraval-mix application

Tags: reactjs, laravel-mix

I have added `laravel-mix` in my `React application. Below is my code

My `webpack.mix.js` looks like the following

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('src/scripts.ts', '/dist/')
    .sass('src/styles.scss', '/dist/')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
    })

    .disableSuccessNotifications()
    .webpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                },
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.vue', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        },
    });
```

My `package.json` scripts and dependeinces looks like the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/node-polyglot": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.4",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.25",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "sass": "^1.35.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-idiomatic-css": "^1.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^8.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
```

I am able to successfully compile the application using `npm run dev` I also get notifications on my desktop `Laravel Mix Build Successful`, but when I run `php artisan serve` I get the below error
`Could not open input file: artisan`

Anyone has gone through this problem? I am in the root directory when I run this command.